# How to open cls files with overleaf ? thanks

Tags: overleaf, import

I am new to writing a dissertation and I am using overleaf. my professor sent us a cls file called "muthesis" but I don't know how to use overleaf to import the templates into it. i would appreciate your help. (ps: the professor only sent this document, not the corresponding pdf)

Comment: The `muthesis` class is already present in overleaf installation. Just starting your document with `\documentclass{muthesis}` should be enough, without need of using the file you received.

Comment: Anyway, in general: to use a custom "private" class, you can add the cls file (e.g. `myname.cls`) to the project folder, and then start your document with `\documentclass{myname}`